# why to build large projects through make files rather than visual studio build?

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

I was studying about the build through make files and was wondering we can also add multiple projects in visual studio then why we still prefer using build through make files....
Have been searching about it but was not able to find some clear answer.
Some things that I found were that using makefiles we can allocate the compiler for every module etc

If you know it Please tell me why shouldn't we use visual studio to build large projects rather than through make files???

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team uses makefiles to guide **automated builds**.  Since most of our software is set to automatically build after 180 seconds of quiet (after the last check-in), the automated build agent uses the makefile to build it.  Other software that is not under automated builds (usually at an earlier stage of development and under control of a single engineer) can safely be built from within Visual Studio.  But in a large team, that condition usually changes as the software matures, and we convert to automated builds.

This is a high-performance form of [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

In our case, it has less to do with the size of the project and more to do with the size of the team and the maturity of the project.  One-engineer prototypes get built in VS; multi-engineer projects and mature software are under automation.

Comment: what possibly can be the need to rebuild software automatically after some time??

Comment: That is a common practice in professional software shops.  If someone checks in code that breaks the automated build, or breaks automated unit testing, we want to know about it in minutes, not the next day.  No one is allowed to leave until the problem is resolved so that one engineer's mistake doesn't delay the whole team.

Comment: fare enough.... so we will be doing the automated build thing on server where we are sharing the source codes with other engineers?

Comment: We use dedicated servers that do nothing but build the software.  We also have dedicated servers that house the source code repository.  Developers only have _copies_ of the source on their machines, except for new code. 
 Please see the article I mention in my edited answer.

Comment: okay...and that automated build is not possible using visual studio or any other method other than make files?

Comment: We use makefiles in MSBuild format.  There are probably other ways but that's how we do it (all Microsoft shop).  If my answer helps your understanding, please upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Embedded engineer here: We also use Makefiles for automated builds where I work. We can then automatically build statistics on the code (size, etc), and we can/could run some simple system tests to see if at least the product still starts normally. 
This is very useful to detect the point where the build starts to fail. It helps finding the exact issue